# First Result Only Using Google-Search-API

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, google-search-api

I am using abenassi/Google-Search-API https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API to make multiple Google queries in a small python script. I typically only need the first result (link) but the program is built to collect whole pages of results. So far I have been limiting the result as such:

```
results = google.search(query)
    for result in iter(results[0:1]):
        loc = result.link
```

The problem is that the script is slow as a result (I think) of having to wade through the whole page before I get my one link. Does anyone see something obvious I'm missing, or alternately, a simple way to modify the standard_search module https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API/blob/master/google/modules/standard_search.py to limit results to first link only? Thanks!

Comment: It says by default it searches 1 page only (a second parameter, `num_page`, can increase this). I suggest you look at all the results once and make sure it really is looking at more then a single page. If it is not, than it's just a connection/API issue you cannot really fix beyond using a different API, and if that fails, getting a faster connection. If it really is looking at more than one page, that seems like a bug and you should post a ticket tat the repo.

Comment: BTW: `results = google.search(query)[0].link` should be enough. No need for the loop, and there is never a reason to `iter` a `list` - it supports iteration by default.

Comment: @kabanus Yes I have the results limited to 1 page, so I think you are right about it being not the quite right API for my needs. Also thanks for the BTW.